# "Has A" or "Belongs To" relationship or something else?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, entity-relationship

I'm not sure why I'm struggling with this it seems like a very simple concept. So my struggling makes me think that perhaps my data modeling needs another component...

I'm using Laravel 5 and am trying to define some model relationships.  `BelongsTo`,`HasA`, etc.  Before I can write the code, I need to at least conceptually understand what type of relationship I'm creating.

I have an application to where users can send people referral links, if a person clicks on the link and signs up, their user record makes note of the code that referred them.  This way I can trace back and see who referred a particular user.  But a referral is NOT necessary to sign up

Tables:

**USERS**

```
+----+-------------+
| id | referral_id |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | 1           |
|  2 | null        |
|  3 | 2           |
+----+-------------+
```

**REFERRALS**

```
+----+---------------+---------+
| id | referral_code | user_id |
+----+---------------+---------+
|  1 |         12345 |       2 |
|  2 |         54321 |       2 |
|  3 |         99999 |       2 |
+----+---------------+---------+
```

`USERS.REFERRAL_ID` references `REFERRALS.ID`
and
`REFERRALS.USER_ID` references `USERS.ID`

But what kind of relationships are these?
The only one that seems obvious to me is that `REFERRALS.USER_ID` **belongs to** `USERS`.

But what about `USERS.REFERRAL_ID`, saying it `belongsTo` Referrals doesn't feel right, as that record isn't required and I don't feel like it 'owns' the user by any means.  Saying it `hasA` referral doesn't feel correct either, as again the user doesn't own or even require the referral.

I guess what is confusing me is that `REFERRALS` is an optional entity.

How should I conceptualize the relationship between `USERS.REFERRAL_ID` and `REFERRALS.ID`?

Is it bad to have this sort of "circular reference"? Would I be better off creating a pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

No need to add any reference to the Referrals table in the User table, you already have that relation defined in the referral table ( user_id column )

Further reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

The Relationship is

```
USER has many REFERRALS 
REFERRAL belongs to USER ( inviter )
REFERRAL belongs to USER ( invitee )
```

Modify your REFERRALS table

```
+----+---------------+---------+------------+
| id | referral_code | user_id | invitee_id |
+----+---------------+---------+------------+
|  1 |         12345 |       2 |          1 |
|  2 |         54321 |       1 |       null |
|  3 |         99999 |       3 |          1 |
+----+---------------+---------+------------+
```

user_id is the id of the user that sends the invitation

invitee_id is the id of the user that accepts and registers

invitee_id column is nullable() and will contain the id of the invitee from users table when they join.

Think of it as a JOIN table between inviter and invitee.